# Moving objectes on the screen have blur

Tags: unity-game-engine

for more then several weeks im struggling with this problem; every time i move my "ship" or any other 2d or 3d objects on the screen - the seems blury and somting leave a ghost like textur on the screen for a few milliseconds.

i tried to solve this problem with a few ways but no sucsess:

1. png -> jpeg/bmp - nothing happend
2. update() -> fixedUpdate() / fixedUpdate() -> update() - NOPE
3. vSync on(default) to off - a very small difrense
4. AA from off to x8 - help a bit more then vSync but still, its blury like hell
5. simplifed the sprite to a smalled texture(by size) and by cutting the wings and making it smaller - did nothing
6. changing the way i move it (Rigidbody2D.position <---> transform.Translate) - didnt to much.
7. joystick(gamepad) and keyboard are the same

i have no idea what to do from now, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any way of providing an image or video of what you describe?

Comment: yes! , https://goo.gl/photos/uPLjEwrUAxFnfqVa7 here - sorry for the low res, and ignore the cube(its was my 3d test). tell me if you can access the video

Answer (score 0):

That looks like strobing - it happens when fast animated movements are done at less than 60 FPS. Our brain feels the jittery movement and makes it noticeable. The two common ways of avoiding it are (a) increasing your target framerate (Application.targetFrameRate) and/or (b) simulating motion blur either with a post-processing effect or manually via sprite swapping.